# React Material-UI - TablePagination - onChangePage is not a function

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I have upgraded from Material-UI v4 to v5 and am now getting the following error:

**TypeError: onChangePage is not a function**

```
function handleNextButtonClick(row) {
 >    onChangePage(row, page + 1);
}
```

It appears that the `onChangePage` prop is now undefined within the `TablePaginationActions` component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Material-UI v5 the prop name has changed from `onChangePage` to `onPageChange`.

I simply had to change the property name in the `TablePagination` component, as well as in all places where this prop is used within the `TablePaginationActions` component.

To simplify migration to v5 I recommend to go through all breaking changes on [this official page](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/)

Comment: Its deprecated in later version of v4 as well.  Just upgraded to 4.11 from 4.2 and its yelling at me to change these and other functions.